# Replace for deprecated CdkDropListContainer

Tags: angular-material

I have a question for someone familiar with Angular Material CDK.

In one of my projects I'm using CdkDropListContainer of Drag&Drop CDK. Unfortunately it was deprecated since v.8.

So here my question: Does someone know how to use CdkDropListContainer functionality in newest version of Material CDK?

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`CdkDropList`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropList), a container that wraps a set of draggable items.

There are several [examples](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples) on the official [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) site. Press the right located [image] buttons to open them in StackBlitz.